# vue js 3 route does not work - does not change route

Tags: vue.js

index.js

```js
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";
import Home from "@/views/Home.vue";
import About from "@/views/About.vue";
import Blog from "@/views/Blog.vue";
import Services from "@/views/Services.vue";
import Contact from "@/views/Contact.vue";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    name: "About",
    component: About,
  },
  {
    path: "/services",
    name: "Services",
    component: Services,
  },
  {
    path: "/blog",
    name: "Blog",
    component: Blog,
  },
  {
    path: "/contact",
    name: "Contact",
    component: Contact,
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

app.vue

```js
<template>
  <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> 
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
      <router-link to="/services">Services</router-link>
      <router-link to="/contact">Contact</router-link>
      <router-link to="/blog">Blog</router-link>
  </div>
  <router-view />
</template>
```

main.js

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'


import router from './router'  


createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

[image]

My codes are in here. There is no change when i press about,services etc.

What am i wrong there, i couldn't find.

when i write on the browser like localhost:8081/about  its not working. It goes to localhost:8081

What is the problem, if you help me i will be glad. Thank you

Comment: Hi, where `#app` is defined? You want to mount in the app but there is no tag with id app.

Comment: Do you have setup any other things like navigation guards?

Comment: Your exact code works fine in this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/troubleshooting-vue-router-iwmoo). Can you update that sandbox to reproduce the issue?